# Angular 2 TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm using Chrome 51 and Angular 2.rc4 and following errors popup in the console when loading my angular app.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null
at e.supportsWebAnimation (platform-browser.umd.js:2232)
at st (platform-browser.umd.js:2896)
at t._instantiate (core.umd.js:6370)
at t._instantiateProvider (core.umd.js:6311)
at t._new (core.umd.js:6300)
at t.getObjByKeyId (core.umd.js:5954)
at t._getByKeyDefault (core.umd.js:6480)
at t._getByKey (core.umd.js:6452)
at t._getByReflectiveDependency (core.umd.js:6442)
at t._instantiate (core.umd.js:6342)
at c (vendors.js:3)
at vendors.js:3
at t.invokeTask (vendors.js:3)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:9091)
at t.invokeTask (vendors.js:3)
at t.runTask (vendors.js:3)
at s (vendors.js:3)
at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (vendors.js:3)
```

If i refresh it again it disappears and the app loads fine. When i dig into it a bit more, i found out the following problematic code where the `body` of the document seems to be `null` in file `platform-browser.umd.js`.

```
BrowserDomAdapter.prototype.supportsWebAnimation = function () {
        return isFunction(document.body['animate']);
};
```

I am using systemjs-builder for bundline the angular components, like so:

```
//Bundle auth module to a single script file
gulp.task('bundle_auth', ['bundle_vendors'], function() {
var builder_auth = new Builder('', 'assets/js/dependencies/config/auth.system.js');
return builder_auth
    .buildStatic('assets/app/auth/main.js', 'assets/dist/js/auth/bundle.js', { minify: true, sourceMaps: true })
    .then(function() {
        //console.log('Build complete for auth module');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

And here is my `systemjs` config, if needed:

```
(function(global) {

// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app' : 'assets/app/auth',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'ng2-translate': 'node_modules/ng2-translate',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs', // added this map section
    'primeng': 'node_modules/primeng',
    'angular2-recaptcha': 'node_modules/angular2-recaptcha'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'assets/app/auth/main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'primeng': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'angular2-recaptcha': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
};

var packageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'forms',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router'
];

// Individual files (~300 requests):
function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}
// Bundled (~40 requests):
function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}

// Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

// Add package entries for angular packages
packageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

var config = {
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    map: map,
    packages: packages
};

System.config(config);

})(this);
```

This issue only happens in chrome.

**EDIT**

Here is the angular bootstrap file:

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './component/app.component';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {HttpService} from '../common/service/http.service';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';
import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '../routes/auth.routes';
import {TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS, TranslateService, TranslatePipe, TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';

enableProdMode();
bootstrap(AppComponent,[
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS,
    HttpService,
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms()
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Could you add your angular bootstrap file ?

Comment: @n00dl3 I have added the bootstrap file

Answer (score 4):

I think you include your bundled js files inside of the head section in the index.html but you should transfer those to the body part under your app.

For being more clear after i transfered my application to webpack i had exactly same issue.

For example,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="">

    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <script src="prod/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="prod/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <app-one>
        Loading...
    </app-one>
</body>

</html>
```

I transferred scripts like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="">

    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>

<body>
    <app-one>
        Loading...
    </app-one>
  
    <script src="prod/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="prod/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Same problem here, and your solution fixed the problem, thanks!