# Chrome Developer "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null" in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, fadein, getelementbyid, ng-animate

**Goal**: animate fadein an element with Typescript in Angular using

```
document.getElementById("elementID").animate
```

I used the example (changed it a bit) [from developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate#Browser_compatibility)

Expected: to work without errors.

Actual results: code works but has Chrome developer errors.

Chrome error details:

> core.js:3838 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null
>
> at PlywoodHebComponent.push../src/app/components/plywood-heb/plywood-heb.component.ts.PlywoodHebComponent.fadeIn (plywood-heb.component.ts:22)
>   at PlywoodHebComponent.push../src/app/components/plywood-heb/plywood-heb.component.ts.PlywoodHebComponent.getChildEvent (plywood-heb.component.ts:18)
>   at PlywoodHebComponent_Template_app_plywood_side_navbar_stringOutput_2_listener (template.html:3)
>   at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:14739)
>   at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:14774)
>   at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:24856)
>   at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:192)
>   at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:130)
>   at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:76)
>   at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)

**UPDATE:**

What I tried: I saw that if I erase the *ngIf , the problem is gone. What means that the element is being checked for it's id on the fadeIn() before it appears in the DOM. I think I should use visibility instead of *ngIf.

Some code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="sidebar">
    <text-style2-container>
        <app-plywood-side-navbar (stringOutput)=getChildEvent($event)></app-plywood-side-navbar>
    </text-style2-container>
</nav>
<article>
    <div class="description-text" *ngIf="imageName=='twin';">
        <text-style1-container>
            <app-twin-heb></app-twin-heb>
        </text-style1-container>
    </div>
    <div class="description-text" *ngIf="imageName=='okoume';">
        <text-style1-container>
            <app-okoume-heb></app-okoume-heb>
        </text-style1-container>
    </div>
    <div class="description-text" *ngIf="imageName=='birch';">
        <text-style1-container>
            <app-birch-heb></app-birch-heb>
        </text-style1-container>
    </div>
</article>
<div class="image-box" *ngIf="imageName;">

    <!-- "image" id element is fading in using the typescript but has errors on chrome developer mode -->

    <img id="image" src="../../../assets/images/plywoods/{{imageName}}-plywood.jpg" alt="{{imageName}} plywood">

</div>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-plywood-heb',
  templateUrl: './plywood-heb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plywood-heb.component.css']
})
export class PlywoodHebComponent {
  imageName: string;
  getChildEvent($event) {
    this.imageName = $event;
    this.fadeIn();  
  }
  fadeIn(): void {
    document.getElementById("image").animate([
      // keyframes
      { opacity: '0' },
      { opacity: '1' }
    ], {
      duration: 2000,
    });
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar, .image-box, .description-text, img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: right;
}
.sidebar, .image-box, .description-text {
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 150px;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 15%; 
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.image-box, .description-text {
    width: 40%;
}
.image-box {
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
img {
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 100px;

    /* fading in animation for autoran plywood route */
    animation-name: fadeInAnimation;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}
.description-text {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
    from { opacity: 0;}
    to { opacity: 1;}
}
```

**Edit:** attaching also index.html as it doesn't have js In it.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>אורי גרוס עצים ולבידים</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
    <app-Layout></app-Layout>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519834/angular-2-typeerror-cannot-read-property-animate-of-null

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply - I am attaching also my index.html file. I have no Js on it So this is not the right solution for my problem.

Comment: You should dive into how angular works a bit more. This is not the solution you should be looking for I’m afraid. A document selector straight inside your component like this will never work as intended.

Comment: @UriGross can you check is document.getElementById("image") throwing undefined or null value?

Comment: Interesting. I see on the console that it has a "null" value on the Initial state. But after I click on the menu that changes elements in this component ( on the html you can see *ngIF) It logs [object HTMLImageElement]. I think I should solve the "null" value in the initial state in order that it would work.

Answer (score 0):

@MikeOne : I found the solution for my code.
@Arunkumar Ramasamy : Thank you for showing me what to check.
I fixed it by changing my html code after understanding that the *ngIf is causing the problem and I might just hide the element and not to destroy it. So I changed just the display of the element. I attach the html code:

```
<div class="image-box" [style.display]="imageName? 'block' : 'none'">
```